# Does milk make eggs more fluffy?

Tags: scrambled-eggs

I just heard that putting milk in eggs make it more fluffy, but is it really a good idea? Some people say putting milk/cream in eggs makes it more fluffy, but some people say that it makes the eggs loses flavor. So, is is it true that putting milk in eggs make it more fluffy?

Comment: there's a good chance that this will be closed as 'opinion based', but see http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/997/67

Comment: No, but I'm not asking about an opinion. I'm asking about the true scientific explanation if putting milk is good or not.

Comment: Nathan, perhaps this is a translation issue ... but you have two questions : "... but is it really a good idea" and "So, is it a good idea or not?".  That's asking for opinions, as some people may prefer flavor over fluffiness  (or use other tricks to get the fluffiness, rather than the crutch of using fat or extra liquid).  If you had asked "Is it true?", that could possibly be scientific.  You could've also asked why milk makes the eggs fluffier.

Comment: I changed it, so can you answer it now? (I have very little experience with cooking, and the only thing I know how to cook is eggs and fried rice) Vote it up! Just kidding... :D

Comment: "Good or not" is opinion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While adding milk may change the flavor slightly, such a small amount is used that it is not likely to be an extreme loss of flavor.

Some people add a small amount of water. With a small amount, flavor loss should not be noticeable. And since most people scramble their eggs with butter or some other type of oil, there is a measure of fat included. (Ref. to below quote.)

[Yahoo Food](https://www.yahoo.com/style/7-facts-you-didnt-know-about-eggs-114499890668.html)  explains the effect and differences:

> Some recipes for scrambled eggs call for water or milk. Does this do anything for the eggs?
>
> When eggs are scrambled, the mechanism that transforms the liquidy beaten eggs into a fluffy mound on the plate is protein coagulation—the process by which, when exposed to heat, proteins unfold and then tangle up with one another and set, forming a latticed gel. The more tender the scrambled eggs, the more loosely the proteins have coagulated. Adding water to scrambled eggs dilutes the proteins a little, thereby raising the temperature at which they coagulate and making it harder to overcook the scramble. Water also increases the amount of steam, which puffs up the eggs, producing fluffy scrambled eggs. As for milk, it contains water but also fat, which coats the protein molecules so that they can’t bind with one another as tightly. The key to scrambled eggs that are both fluffy and tender is a balance of water and fat.

Also you can choose not to add anything and just whisk the eggs *very* well before cooking. This will incorporate air and result in fluffier eggs.

In the end, it will be your choice. I would suggest trying all three ways and deciding which you like best.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the thing that makes the eggs more fluffy is whisking them before cooking, since you allow particles of air to be introduced among the eggs, then due to heat these air particles will expand a little givving more volume to your eggs.

However milk or cream give more nutrients to your meal, and yes decreases the eggs flavor a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes in my experience eggs will fluff more with milk.  Some people like that.

Yes milk will change the flavor.  Some people like that flavor.

When you mix the milk helps it to become homogeneous.  In bulk I would mix the eggs slow and then add just enough whole milk or cream to get it blend out.

It is more about how you cook them.  If you keep the egg(s) moving they will fluff more.  With milk even more.

Answer (score 0):

I've been cooking scrambled eggs since I was 12. I've made them all types of ways: without anything, with water, with milk, with cream, etc. I can tell you absolutely without a doubt that MILK does the trick and makes the eggs fluffier. The trick is to use a decent amount of milk. 2 ounces of milk is not going to make a noticeable difference. I have been doing it for so long that I don't need to measure, but I eyeball about 1/3 portion of milk in proportion to the amount of eggs.

Comment: Please note that this site, like the whole Stack Exchange network has a Code of Conduct - and that we enforce it.